# Saving images as nsdata to plist and receiving memory warning

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, image, memory-management

My app allows users to take a photo and store it on their phone in order to refer to it later on. I have stored other user information in a plist, and am trying to do the same to the images. After the camera takes the picture, the UIImage is converted into NSData (using UIImagePNGRepresentation) and stored in the plist. The only problem is that after two or three images are stored, the app receives a memory warning and crashes. I would greatly appreciate if someone could tell me a more efficient method to store the images in the plist. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should provide us more detailed information such as the code while you are saving.

Comment: The most efficient method of storing images in plist is not to store images in plist.

Comment: you need to post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you dont save the image to the plist, save the image to your Documents folder and the path to that image in the plist.

Comment: how do i save the image tot the documents folder

Comment: see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037432/saving-image-to-documents-directory-and-retrieving-for-email-attachment

Comment: @Rafael.S i'm still receiving a memory warning and the app is still crashing

Answer (score 0):

You can use/try save on filesystem, every app in iOS is sandbox and has access to his own document folder.

what i suggest to write on filesystem and save the urls on the database as that is more performant than saving blobs on a database.

Apple has a good write up about the iOS [filesystem.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Or

if You are cannot/won't to save anything inside the app's bundle. you can use `+[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` to store the image in your app's documents directory

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myImageURL];
NSString *imagePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/myImage.png"];
[imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

or

useful link [save-and-get-image-from-plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620887/save-and-get-image-from-plist)

helpful link [how-to-store-an-image-path-in-a-plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222629/how-to-store-an-image-path-in-a-plist)